# Recursion error with if statement when changing items in PYQT5 table python

Tags: python, pyqt5, recursionerror

I have a table in pyqt5 and when I modify a cell I call a method(changeIcon), inside this method I use an if statement to check which column has been changed and based on the column I change some items, everytime I modify the column 3 and 4 it returns me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\FOLDER\App.py", line 291, in Change_method
RecursionError
```

This is the code :

```
def tabledata(self)
    .....
    self.tabella_registrazioni.itemChanged.connect(self.changeIcon) 
    .....

def changeIcon(self, item):
    row = item.row()
    col = item.column()
    custcode = self.tabella_registrazioni.item(row, 3).text()
    custname = self.tabella_registrazioni.item(row, 4).text()
    if col == 3 :
        if not custcode.isspace() and custcode != " " and custcode != "":
            cname = d.execute("SELECT 1 FROM CODES WHERE ANCODICE = ?", (custcode)).fetchone()[0]
            if cname != None:
                self.tabella_registrazioni.setItem(row, 4, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(cname)))
    if col == 4 :
        if not custname.isspace() and custname != " " and custname != "":
            ccode = d.execute("SELECT 2 FROM CODES WHERE ANDESCRI = ?", (custname)).fetchone()[0]
            if ccode != None:
                self.tabella_registrazioni.setItem(row, 3, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(ccode)))
```

Comment: Please include the full traceback error.

Comment: I did it but it doesn't give any additional information

Comment: What is the ```Change_method```?

Comment: it's the name of the function, this if statements is inside the Change_method and line 291 it's the line that starts with cname = d.execute(".....

Comment: Ensure that you *do* get the full traceback, by running the code in a prompt or terminal. Also, please provide a [mre].

Comment: The traceback is complete, I find out why it returned that error , everytime I change the item of the column 3 or 4 it gives a signal and calls this method, so when I try to change the column 4 automatically the column 3 changes based on column 4, but when the columns 3 changes the column 4 changes as well, this for infinte times.
The solution was to block signals before setting the item and to enable them after I set the item

Comment: @IT-SRL That answer is insufficient, since the question is incomplete. Nobody would find this useful because nobody would be able to understand the source of the problem. I'll say this for one last time, as this is not the first nor the second that you keep making the same mistake: we can not answer if the question does not provide enough details (meaning at least the function definition and how it's called, otherwise a MRE). How could we know that you had signals connected to that function? How could anybody understand the problem without even knowing how that function got called?

Comment: @musicamente I wrote the missing part (where I connect the item changed signal to the method), now I guess it's pretty clear why it didn't work, also I hope the solution is written pretty clearly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find out why it returned that error , everytime I change the item of the column 3 or 4 it gives a signal and calls this method, so when I try to change the column 4 automatically the column 3 changes based on column 4, but when the columns 3 changes the column 4 changes as well, this for infinte times. The solution was to block signals before setting the item and to enable them after I set the item :

```
self.tabella_registrazioni.blockSignals(True)
self.tabella_registrazioni.setItem(row, 3, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(ccode)))
self.tabella_registrazioni.blockSignals(False)
```